# Winter bashing with find

Tags: bash, command, find

Recently (that is in winter in few days) I wrote a simple script which packs some folders, script is listed below:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for DIR in `find -name "MY_NAME*" -type d`
do
tar -zcvf $DIR.tar.gz $DIR &
done
echo "Packing is done" > packing.txt
```

It works fine except that it searches for `MY_NAME*` in every sub-directory of the folder where it runs.
Because `MY_NAME*` folders contain lots of files, and packing takes long hours, I want to limit time loss and I want the `find` command to find those `MY_NAME*` directories only within the folder where the script is running (without sub-directories). Is it possible with command `find` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use the `-maxdepth` flag on the `find` command:

```
find -name "MY_NAME*" -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want it only in the folder you are in, don't use find. Try this:

```
for DIR in MY_NAME*/
   do
   tar -zcvf "$DIR".tar.gz "$DIR" &
done
echo "Packing is done" > packing.txt
```

Comment: I have to admit, for a long time I was an abuser of `for file in $(ls *.c)` before someone pointed out just use the shell glob by itself. And wow is that easier

Comment: @DrakeClarris your answer is great too, but as for me my version with `find` is more readable to me! anyway thanks for quick response!

Comment: If you want to limit to *directories* starting with "MY_NAME", use `for dir in MY_NAME*/` (with the trailing slash)

Comment: Wow I don't know why I hadn't thought of that. Always learning something new when it comes to linux. Gonna edit that one in. Thanks